# django: A good way of inserting or updating a large list of objects

Tags: django, django-orm

It looks like I have a problem working with a large dataset. Lets say I have the following case:

1) A large csv (200K+ lines) with products (each one with a unique sku), is sent with a post request
2) For each item I need to check if it's already in database (I was using get_or_create)
3) In case object exists I do update it, otherwise I create a new entity in database.

The code looks like this:

```
for csv_item in csv_products:
    product = Products.objects.get_or_create(sku=csv_item.sku)
    product.price = csv_item.price # Here I update all fields from csv_item
    product.save()
```

**The issue**
This code creates unbelievable hit to the database. The amount of queries is amazing, and the execution time as well...

What i was trying:
1) Bulk create method of django. Why it did not work well: I need not only to create but to update as well. So checking if object exists on first step break bulk_create...
2) Controlling transactions manually by sending commit/rollback. Not sure here... it tends to give me integrity errors.

Please advise..

Comment: You may want to consider using a task queue like [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) and update the prices as a background process. That doesn't reduce the number of queries, but it does mean that you can quickly return a response to the user that says "thanks for uploading, the prices will be updated".

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about it. But anyway, I can't predict the amount of rows per uploaded file... I wonder if it will not kill my server at some point, as I am kind of making 3 db queries per row...

Comment: Definitely use a task queue. I don't think it would kill your server unless you are getting a ton of csv files. If so might be time to spin up another server. Another thought is to process the csv files. Get a list of sku's. Check if they are in the db with `.filter(sku__in=list)`. Get a diff of them then do a `bulk_create` of the ones that aren't in there already. From there update all the existing ones.

Comment: You might want to check out [django-bulk-update](https://github.com/aykut/django-bulk-update)

Comment: As I see django-bulk-updates uses some sql script. And I think it will not work out for my case. As some objects may already be in the database, but some are definitely not... so that update sql will not work

Comment: if you change `product = Products.objects.get_or_create(sku=csv_item.sku)` to `product, created = Products.objects.get_or_create(sku=csv_item.sku)` you can just do a check if the item needs to be updated or saved, and append them to a specific list. Then call the bulk_create on one and bulk_update on the other.

Comment: Is your `sku` field correctly indexed in the DB?